# Find the value of $k$ for which matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> Consider the matrix
>
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
>         1 & 0 & 1 \\
>         0 & 2 & k \\
>         0 & 0 & 2 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}$$
>   where $k$ is a real number.
>
> The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(λ −1)(λ−2)^2$. Find the value of $k$ for which the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable
>   and write down a matrix $P$ which diagonalizes $A$ for this value of $k$.

I have attempted the problem by trying to find eigenspaces and hence the basis, to get the matrix $P$. Tried row reducing and other things, but can't seem to get anywhere. I feel like there is a theorem which relates the characteristic polynomial and diagonalizable matrix, but I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Right, we can read off the characteristic polynomial from the diagonal: $$p(\lambda) = (\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)^2.$$Call the matrix $A$. If the matrix is to be diagonalizable, we must obtain a basis of eigenvectors. We need three vectors. In other words, since $$\dim(\ker(A-{\rm Id})) \geq 1, \quad \dim(\ker(A-2\,{\rm Id})) \geq 1,$$ and $1$ is a simple root of $p(\lambda)$, we have $\dim(\ker(A-{\rm Id}))=1$. So $\dim(\ker(A-2\,{\rm Id}))$ had better be $2$. $$A-2\,{\rm Id } = \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & k \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$ From this it is clear that we get what we want for $k=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Matrix is Diagonalizable if and only if minimal polynomial is of the form

$$p(x)=(x-c_1)(x-c_2)...(x-c_k)$$

where $c_1,c_2,...,c_k$ are distinct eigen values of matrix.

Here in your case matrix will be diagonalizable if and only if 
 $$(A-\,{\rm I })(A-2\,{\rm I })=0$$
$$(A-\,{\rm I })(A-2\,{\rm I }) = \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & k \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & k \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & k \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$. Hence for $k=0$  matrix is diagonalizable.